# What is the "UP development methodologies"?

Tags: methodology

I just seen a job advert ask for "UP development methodologies"

What is it?

Or has the HT department got the job spec wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is referring to the "Unified process" set of methodologies. Check out this [link](http://wapedia.mobi/en/Unified_Process).

Small summary taken from link:

> The Unified Process is an iterative
>   and incremental development process.
>   The Elaboration, Construction and
>   Transition phases are divided into a
>   series of timeboxed iterations. (The
>   Inception phase may also be divided
>   into iterations for a large project.)
>   Each iteration results in an
>   increment, which is a release of the
>   system that contains added or improved
>   functionality compared with the
>   previous release.

Comment: So RUP without the payment to IBM/Rational ....

Answer (score 2):

There is no mistake ...
UP means **Unified Process.**.

UP is a ***genaral process framework***...It should be customized/make it to be more concrete before to use it...**Think it as an abstract class in object oriented programming  :-)**

People takes this "abstract" process framework, make it more concrete and adapt it to their situtaion...As a convention you put some prefix on it to show that this is customized version of that process framework...**Rational as  firm create this abstract process framework and then make their own concrete framework from it, put their firm capital letter R on it...So we get RUP :-)...To make analogy think RUP (Rational Unified Process) as a concrete subclass of abstract UP class :-**)

But in practice Unified Process [UP] itself is so abstract that unless you are so experienced process guy or  you have  curiosity about "processes" you not bother with it...Generally you bother with its concrete implementation RUP  etc...**In practice so UP and RUP mean same thing...but  in theory they may not...**

Here is some UP development methodologies:

- RUP ( Rational UP )
- EssUP ( Essential Unified Process ) [ Ivar Ivar Jacobson]
- AgileUP [ Scott W. Ambler ]

And maybe  in the future you will create **IUP** which is Ian Ringrose^s UP :-)

Answer (score 1):

Typo for Rational Unified Process (RUP) maybe?

Comment: No, not a typo. They removed the "R" to avoid trademark issues (the RUP trademark belongs to IBM, originally to Rational).

Answer (score 1):

I would guess UP means RUP - [Rational Unified Process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Rational_Unified_Process).

Answer (score 1):

UP is a generic way of saying RUP (Rational Unified Process)

Check:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Process

Comment: Presumably it also covers irrational unified processes too...

Answer (score 0):

UP, the Unified Process, is the process-side companion to UML.